# Overheating and battery draining problems on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, dell, battery, overheating, dell-vostro

I had bought a Dell Vostro 3500 laptop (Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7, Graphics: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics) and I started to use Ubuntu. In a short time I noticed that the laptop was heating up quickly and the battery life was much worse than it should have been. I made a dual boot (Windows 10 Pro, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) to check out the difference between the behavior of the laptop. Under Windows the results were stunning: much less heating, way better performance from the perspective of the battery. Then I tried to install TLP (on Ubuntu) and that maybe helped a bit to reduce the temperature of the laptop but the battery life was also bad. I couldn't install official dell drivers using wine. Did you meet with these kind of problems? If so, please help me with mine. :)